# Rings for which the Köthe conjecture holds

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, conjectures, nilpotence

Is there an overview of rings for which the [Köthe conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6the_conjecture) is known to hold? In particular, I am interested in endomorphism rings of graded modules over multivariate polynomial rings. [This survey](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/62658213.pdf) states that the conjecture holds for left artinian rings (alas, without a reference). However, in the notion of that survey, to hold means that "the ideal generated by every nil left ideal of R is nil."

So my explicit question is: In any left artinian ring, or in a particular special case thereof, is it true that the sum of two left nil ideals is nil again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because in a left Artinian ring nil left ideals are nilpotent, and the sum of two nilpotent left ideals is always nilpotent.